# Multiple actions from a single submit on a web form

Tags: php

I have a webform with a PayPal donate button.
How do I setup so that when the user clicks the submit button the details of the form are sent to my email address and then secondly the user is directed to PayPal to make the donation?

Thank-you.

Comment: You set the `action` attribute of the form to be the url of your php script which handles the request. In your script you call php `mail()` function and after that you call php `Header('Location: www.paypal.com/etc.../?query=bla&query2=blo&etc')` which will redirect the user to paypal.

Comment: @Stefan Write this comment as an answer.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: OK, did that - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
// ...
if(mail([...])) { // try to send email
    header("Location: http://PayPal.com/..."); // If mail was sent successfully the user will be redirected
}
else {
// error sending mail
}
?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php for using mail()-function.

Comment: Good idea, but it's a pity your example is incomplete and therefore it may be harder to understand. You should have put some relevant comments before the if/else block, but still, nice approach ;-)

Comment: I don't think a simple if/else like this would need lots of commenting @VictorNitu

Comment: I don't know... based on the question, I'm not sure of the OP's level of knowledge, no pun intended, I just encourage explicit answers.

Comment: Thank-you. Can u explain how the parameters in the Paypal URL should be set out? ie www.paypal.com/etc.../?query=bla&query2=blo&etc. What should be put instead of query=blo etc.

Comment: @DRP96 Thank-you. Can u explain how the parameters in the Paypal URL should be set out? ie www.paypal.com/etc.../?query=bla&query2=blo&etc. What should be put instead of query=blo etc

Comment: Sorry, therefor I need to know how this checkout with PayPal exactly works, so I don't know how the URL should be. Maybe you could look here https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/merchant?nav=2 and maybe contact the support.

Comment: @DRP96 I worked it out.  "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=*****&amount=$Amount&item_name=donation";

Comment: Okay, you know how to get the variables (like $Amount)?

Answer (score 2):

You set the `action` attribute of the form to be the url of your php script which handles the request. In your script you call php `mail()` function and after that you call php `Header('Location: www.paypal.com/etc.../?query=bla&query2=blo&etc')` which will redirect the user to paypal.

Comment: Thank-you.  Can u explain how the parameters in the Paypal URL should be set out? ie www.paypal.com/etc.../?query=bla&query2=blo&etc. What should be put instead of query=blo etc..

Comment: Thank-you. Can u explain how the parameters in the Paypal URL should be set out? ie www.paypal.com/etc.../?query=bla&query2=blo&etc. What should be put instead of query=blo etc